# du + tree command (without tree installation)

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, tree

is there a nice way to combine:

```
ls -R | grep "^[.]/" | sed -e "s/:$//" -e "s/[^\/]*\//--/g" -e "s/^/   |/"
```

(displays directory as tree)

with

```
du -h ... (for each listed dir)
```

Without installing any extra package, like tree, dutree ?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: OP would like to display tree dirs with sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should revert the order of `du -h` with `tac` and then put some formatting with `sed`. This one should work for "normal" directory names (without control characters):

```
du -h | tac | sed 's_[^/[:cntrl:]]*/_--_g;s/-/|/'
```

Or use `find -exec`:

```
find . -type d -exec du -sm {} \; | sed 's_[^/[:cntrl:]]*/_--_g;s/-/|/'
```